# Insert datetime type into created column from PHP file from module/component

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I can't get the `created` column filled when inserting items into the database. I am using this code:

```
function createRecordInLSFCDBTable($id, $userId) {

    echo 'createRecordInLSFCDBTable: ' . $id . ', ' . $userId . '<br>';

    // Collect current date and time
    // Try 1
    // $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    // $date = strtotime($date);

    // Try 2
    // $date = JFactory::getDate('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    // $date = strtotime($date);

    // Try 3
    // $date = JFactory::getDate()->toSql();

    var_dump($date);

    // Get a db connection.
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    // Create a new query object.
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    // Insert columns.
    $columns = array('listingid', 'user', 'created_by', 'created');

    // Insert values.
    $values = array($id, $userId, $userId, $date);

    // Prepare the insert query.
    $query
        ->insert($db->quoteName('#__table'))
        ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
        ->values(implode(',', $values));

    // Set the query using our newly populated query object and execute it.
    $db->setQuery($query);
    $db->execute();

}
```

I first tried without using Joomla functions with result error 1064.

Then tried after some SO & J! forum searching try 2 and result error 1064.

Some more searching brought me by try 3 and this resulted into `Call to a member function toSql() on string`.

When I remove the date from the insert columns and insert values lines then it goes through without any issues. Record is created but I need the `created` column also be filled.

The full output for 1064 is `1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '22:55:38)' at line 3`

Comment: PHP Error logs gives out this by try 1 and 2 `Invalid status line from script 'index.php': 1064` for try 3 it does not give an errorline in the log.

Comment: Quoting strings is necessary; [1](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/14807/12352), [2](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/28937/12352), [3](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32277/12352), [4](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/32344/12352), [5](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/5665/12352), [6](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/14103/12352)

Comment: @mickmackusa You are exactly right about that! I had forgotten that, but when I remembered it, I immediately answered it. I could have deleted the question, but decided to keep it for future users who Google search something related to this question title. As you can see, with all the links you posted (thank you for that!) none of these titles are related to `datetime type` or `created`. Now is hoping I don't get downvoted like crazy. Thank you for your contribution, even after an answer is already posted. That shows some true dedication, and I salute you for that. Have a great day.

Comment: I don't think you should delete this page.  While searching, I found quite a few answers that did not include quoting BECAUSE all columns were integers.  This is somewhat misleading to the untrained eye.  For this reason, this page should be beneficial to future researchers.  My point in providing those links was to help stitch related content together.  Now those pages are easily referenced on the list in the right-side panel of this page (or bottom of the page if you are on a smalls device).

Answer (score 2):

You can improve a bit your code and abrace the best practice of J4

```
<?php

use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\Database\DatabaseAwareTrait;
use Joomla\Database\ParameterType;

class YOUR_CLASS 
{
   function createRecordInLSFCDBTable($id, $userId) 
   {
      $db    = Factory::getContainer()->get(DatabaseInterface::class);
      $query = $db->getQuery(true);

      // Get the current date
      $date = Factory::getDate()->toSql();

      $columns = ['listingid', 'created_by', 'created'];
      $values  = [':rowid', ':createdby', ':created']
      
      // Insert the new records into the table
      $query->insert($db->quoteName('#__table'))
         ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
         ->values(implode(', ', $values))
         ->bind(':rowid', $id, ParameterType::INTEGER)
         ->bind(':createdby', $userId, ParameterType::STRING)
         ->bind(':createddate', $date , ParameterType::INTEGER);
         
         $db->setQuery($query);
         $db->execute();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I forgot that it needed to have `'` around the string. So I solved it by using

```
    $date = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    $date = "'" . $date . "'";
```

Just remove everything from try 1, 2, 3 and replace with the above and it should work.